# how to change the background color of particular item of array list in activity without using selector

Tags: android, background-color

How to change background color of item dynamically or xml for below code:

```
 Button okButton = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.ok1);
                                okButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View v) {

                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                         //                                 loadListViews(invoice1, listView1, //                                           headerButton1);
                                        Connection con1 = DbHandler.dbConnection();
                                        try{
                                        PreparedStatement stmt1 = con1
                                                .prepareStatement("Select Line_No, ItemName,DeleteFlag from PendingOrders_Dtl where Inv_No=? ");

                                        stmt1.setString(1,invNo);
                                        ResultSet rsSetup1 = stmt1.executeQuery();

                                        if (rsSetup1.next()) {
                                            ItemsBean bean1 = new ItemsBean();
                                                bean1.setLinenum(rsSetup1.getInt("Line_No"));
    bean1.setProdnum(rsSetup1.getInt("ItemName"));
                            bean1.setDeleteFlag(rsSetup1.getInt("DeleteFlag"));
                                        disablelist.add(bean1);
                                    }

                                    CustomAdapter adapter1 = new CustomAdapter(PendingOrdersActitvity.this, itemsList1);
                                        for(int i=0;i<itemsList1.size();i++)
                                        {
                                            for(int j=0;j<disablelist.size();j++) {
                                            if(itemsList1.get(i).getProdnum()==disablelist.get(j).getProdnum())
                                            {
itemsList1.get(i).setSelection(true);
                                            }
```

How can I change that `newlist1.get(i)` position background color?

Comment: you can change the bg color if you are using custom layout for the list view ....
or just simply change the bg color of the list view ....it would be visible while selection ...

Comment: actually i have main list  when touch on it i will get popup list as same list of main list what i select in popup list have to change color in main lit . there disable list is selected items of popup window   when there positions are equal have o change color of main liust